# What is the difference between 大凡(おおよそ) and 凡そ(およそ)?

Tags: word-choice

> 彼女の**おおよそ**の年齢しか知らない。 We can only know her approximate age.
>
> 旅は**およそ**５時間くらいかかるでしょう。The trip will take some five hours.

I even found a sentence with both of them:

> １浪で**およそ**20％台の合格率で、2浪以上では**おおよそ**2～3％台とかなり低迷しています。([source](https://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/67786/))

Jisho gives the same definitions for the both:

[おおよそ](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8A%E3%82%88%E3%81%9D)

[およそ](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8A%E3%82%88%E3%81%9D)

I found that in the dictionary of grammar:
[image]

It would mean that all other usages of およそ can't be conveyed by おおよそ or I don't understand this explanation correctly...?

Comment: Perhaps the explanation here could help: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1327621433

From the above explanation, it appears that they are interchangeable in most cases as およそ itself just evolved from おおよそ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「およそ」は「おおよそ」から発音が変化して生まれたようです。
従って、両者は同じ意味であるとする一般的な説明がありますが、実際には次にように少しニュアンスあるいは使われた方違っているように思います。

（１）曖昧さの程度が違う

いずれも「約」あるいは「大体」という意味ですが、実際には、「おおよそ」の方が「およそ」より曖昧さの程度が大きいように思います。
従ってOPが示した最初の「おおよその年齢」では50歳とか60歳とか、10歳単位程度の誤差はありますが、もし、「およその年齢」と言った場合には、50歳前半、50歳半ばあるいは50歳後半という程度の誤差（＝10歳の誤差より少ない誤差）しかないように思います。

「およそ5時間」の例では、話者も読者も5時間プラスマイナス20～30分以内程度、あるいはもっと良い精度を想定しますが、「おおよそ5時間」では4時間から6時間位の大きな誤差を想定します。

この説明を聞くと、「1浪」のケースではうまく説明できないようですが、多分後半の「おおよそ」は、私なら「およそ2～3％台」と書き表｛あらわ｝すところです。あるいは「台」を使わず「およそ2～3％」と書き表すでしょう。「20％台」なら「20数％」を意味しますが、「2～3％」の表現で「台」を使うのは何か変ですね。「2％台」なら「2.数％」という意味ですが、「2～3％台」は実際にはどういう意味なのでしょうか。「2～3％台」が変な表現ですので、「おおよそ」を議論するのに値しない例だとお考え下さい。

（２）「おおよその見当/見方/考え方」

「概略の」あるいは「一般的な」「見当｛けんとう｝/見方｛みかた｝/考えた」を表現するときには、「おおよその見当/見方/考え方」という表現を良く使いますが、「およその見当/見方/考え方」とは余り言わないように思います。

（３）頻度

「およそ」が圧倒的に「おおよそ」より使われます。
この2つの内、「おおよそ」が本来の表現であるとすると、いつの間にかあとから生まれた「およそ」の方が多く使われるようになったのは、世の中が忙しくなったからでしょうか。「おおよそ」は発音すると分かりますが「およそ」よりゆったりとしています。

（４）忙しい人に向いた表現

「およそ」は「おおよそ」より忙しい人に向いているかどうかは知りませんが、せっかちな江戸っ子が啖呵｛たんか｝を切って「およそ」という表現を使います。
ここでは「おおよそ」とは言いません。

「およそ何かい。お前さんが最初に言ったんだって？」